# MongoRestore 4.2 decreases the restored database sizes to half

Tags: mongodb

I'm using **MongoDB 4.0** and taking backups with **MongoDump 4.0**. I need to migrate data from one machine to another meanwhile I'm planing to upgrade to **MongoDB 4.2** as well. I tested below 2 methods:

**Method 1:**
When I restore the dump file created from **MongoDump 4.0** to **MongoDB 4.2** using **MongoRestore 4.2** the sizes of my databases decrease to almost half,i.e, DB1 size drops from 45GB to 27GB and DB2 size drops from 53GB to 40GB. I checked the counts of documents and documents structures as well. Everything is intact.

**Method 2:**
When I restore the same dump file back in **MongoDB 4.0** using **MongoRestore 4.0** the size are same as they were when taking the backup,i.e, DB1 45GB and DB2 53GB. Then I upgraded this MongoDB version from **4.0** to **4.2** using the Documentation the sizes remain the same after version upgrade,i.e,  DB1 45GB and DB2 53GB.

I've repeated this multiple times and result is same. I'm not able to figure out why the size decreases when applying **MongoRestore 4.2** on a dump file taken from **MongoDump 4.0.**

Should I go for the **Method 1** and take advantage of decreased storage space even though it is not recommended to restore the dump file taken from a version of ***MongoDump*** and restore with any other version of ***MongoRestore***.

**Note:** It is not the deletedspace as I've checked with **Stats()** function and I've restored indexes as well.

Answer (score 0):

WiredTiger [supports compression of stored data](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/wiredtiger/#compression). 4.2 adds zstd as a compression option, and perhaps changes the defaults too.

Comment: should it not change the size also when I upgrade from 4.0 to 4.2?

Comment: Maybe. Did you upgrade FCV?

Comment: Yes, upgraded FCV to 4.2. But nothing changed w.r.t storage size

Comment: In that case check the docs to see how to turn on on disk compression and do that.